# How can I use REGEXEXCTRACT to create MULTIPLE sub-strings from a single cell of very long text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my sheet cell A1 contains a  comma-separated text string that is very long.

**A1(example)**=`"value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,...etc.")`

I am using the following regexextract formula so that it extracts the first 1000 characters, but does NOT cut-off the resulting text midway through a comma-separated value. This will ensure that the ending of the string will be the last FULL VALUE that fits.

**cell B1**`=IF(LEN(A1)<=200,A1,REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.{0,1000}),"))`

The function above works perfectly, but I do not know how to make cell B2 start where cell B1 ended in reference to my main text string A1. Meaning if it ended at *value45* in cell B1 in my  example below, I need cell B2 to start right after the comma that was used to end at *value45*, in cell B1's text string.

**B1 (resulting string example)**`"value1,.....,value45"`

I need to do the same function of B1 over and over again in cells B2, B3, B4, etc. until the entire text is extracted in 1000 character sub-string chunks and is completed.

Does anyone know how I can solve this? In future projects, cell A1's character length will always change so I need it to be dynamic for any character lengths greater than 200 character. I also cannot use Script Editor as this is a requirement given to me from management

Comment: If you're using Google Sheets, then the Excel tags are irrelevant (removed). Excel does not have the `REGEXEXTRACT` function. Please only use relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try these formulas:

B1: `=regexextract(A1, "(.{0,1000})(?:,|$)")`

B2: `=regexextract( mid(A$1, len(join(",", B$1:B1)) + 2, len(A$1)), "(.{0,1000})(?:,|$)" )`

You can copy the formula in B2 down to get more values.